# Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, parameters

I have data imported into a temporary table in MSAccess which looks like this:

[image: Temporary table]

to which I have added the "Gap" and "Previous/Current" columns that I need to calculate using an SQL Query. The "Gap Threshold" is User input or **PARAMETER** supplied to Query and for e.g. is 300. The GlobalID groups ItemID's whereas each ItemID is unique number.

What i want to do is calculate the GAP

> (GAP = TEMPORARY_1![VERSION DATE] - TEMPORARY![VERSION DATE])

between ItemID's of similar GlobalID's and identify the items having GAP > GAP THRESHOLD value. Based on this GAP, for each GlobalID-grouped ItemID's, I want to determine which is the "Previous" ItemID and which is the "Current" ItemID.

> i.e. determine which is Previous Item and which is Current Item, having a GAP of more than 300 days between them.

Finally, CREATE ANOTHER TABLE that will only import these Current/Previous Pairs for each GlobalID, but display them as one record each like this:

[image: Final table]

OR Is it a better design to Create 2 separate Tables AFTER CALCULATING GAP > GAP THRESHOLD, called **tblPrevious** & **tblCurrent** from the **Temporary table** like this?:

[image: tblPrevious]

[image: tblCurrent]

I need someone to point me in the right direction to have a better normalized design and achieve this using SQL query. Note: all the tables need to be generated dynamically everytime based on new data extract that is imported.

The below query gives error on Gap column and doesn't calculate Previous/Current:

```
PARAMETERS Threshold Long;
SELECT TEMPORARY.GlobalID, TEMPORARY.ItemID, TEMPORARY.[Version Date], IIf([TEMPORARY]![GlobalID]=
[TEMPORARY_1]![GlobalID],Max([TEMPORARY]![Version Date])-Min([TEMPORARY_1]![Version Date])=0,"Previous") AS Previous, TEMPORARY_1.ItemID, TEMPORARY_1.[Version Date], IIf([TEMPORARY]![GlobalID]=[TEMPORARY_1]![GlobalID],Max([TEMPORARY]![Version Date])-Min([TEMPORARY_1]![Version Date])>[Threshold],"Current") AS [Current], IIf(([TEMPORARY]![Version Date]-[TEMPORARY_1]![Version Date])>[Threshold],[TEMPORARY]![Version Date]-[TEMPORARY_1]![Version Date],"") AS GAP
FROM TEMPORARY, TEMPORARY AS TEMPORARY_1
GROUP BY TEMPORARY.GlobalID, TEMPORARY.ItemID, TEMPORARY.[Version Date], TEMPORARY_1.GlobalID, TEMPORARY_1.ItemID, TEMPORARY_1.[Version Date];
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Review [Allen Browne Subquery](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord).

Requirements described in narrative differ from the title. Here are suggestions for both.

Queries pulling Current/Previous pairs.

Query 1:

> SELECT [GlobalID], [ItemID] AS CurItemID, [Version Date] AS CurDate, (SELECT TOP 1 [Version Date] FROM Temporary AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.GlobalID=Temporary.GlobalID AND Dupe.ItemID < Temporary.ItemID ORDER BY Dupe.GlobalID, Dupe.ItemID DESC) AS PreDate, (SELECT TOP 1 [ItemID] FROM Temporary AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.GlobalID=Temporary.GlobalID AND Dupe.ItemID < Temporary.ItemID ORDER BY Dupe.GlobalID, Dupe.ItemID DESC) AS PreItemID
>   FROM [Temporary];

Query 2:

> SELECT Query1.GlobalID, Query1.CurItemID, Query1.CurDate, Query1.PreDate, Query1.PreItemID, DateDiff("d",[PreDate],[CurDate]) AS Gap FROM Query1 WHERE ((([GlobalID] & [CurItemID]) In (SELECT TOP 1 GlobalID & CurItemID FROM Query1 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.GlobalID = Query1.GlobalID ORDER BY GlobalID, CurItemID DESC))) AND DateDiff("d",[PreDate],[CurDate]) > Int([Enter Threshold]);

Final output:

> GlobalID  CurItemID   CurDate     PreDate     PreItemID Gap
>   00109086    2755630     2/26/2015   3/11/2014   2130881   352
>   00114899    2785590     3/13/2015   3/25/2014   2093191   353
>   00154635    2755623     2/26/2015   4/4/2014    2176453   328

Here is query that addresses the requirement for Minimum/Maximum as stated in your title. Not as slow as the Current/Previous queries but if dataset gets significantly larger I expect it will get very slow.

```
SELECT Maximum.GlobalID, Maximum.ItemID AS MaxItem, Maximum.[Version Date] AS MaxItemDate, Minimum.ItemID AS MinItem, Minimum.[Version Date] AS MinItemDate, Maximum.[Version Date]-Minimum.[Version Date] AS Gap
FROM 
(SELECT T1.GlobalID, T1.ItemID, T1.[Version Date] FROM [Temporary] AS T1 WHERE (((T1.ItemID) In (SELECT Min([ItemID]) AS MinItem FROM Temporary GROUP BY GlobalID)))) AS Minimum 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT T1.GlobalID, T1.ItemID, T1.[Version Date] FROM [Temporary] AS T1 WHERE (((T1.ItemID) In (SELECT Max([ItemID]) AS MaxItem FROM Temporary GROUP BY GlobalID)))) AS Maximum 
ON Minimum.GlobalID = Maximum.GlobalID
WHERE Maximum.[Version Date]-Minimum.[Version Date]>Int([Enter Threshold]);
```

Also, your dates are in international format. If you encounter issues with that, review [Allen Browne International Dates](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html)

Comment: Hi @June7, i think you misunderstood what i want. **First**, in the 1st snapshot, i have manually calculated and added the gap and previous/current columns based on the threshold number. I need to automate calculation of these column using SQL Query. **Second**, i want to create the table(s) in the formats shown in the other snapshots.
Your above query does not yield record. Also there is no "Current" column or the calculation for it, in Query. GAP needs to be calculated first.

Comment: Okay, tried again and revised the answer. The Previous and Current fields really don't seem useful so did not include them.

Comment: Hi @June7 This looks more like it. However, the query result is 735 items. It should be 269 items. The gap should be calculated between the Maxium CurrItemID and Minimum PrevItemID with the same GlobalID.

Comment: Your example output calculates difference between latest [Version Date] and immediately preceding [Version Date]. My query calculates difference between each successive pair of sequential dates. Restricting output to one record for each GlobalID takes another query. Revised the answer again. Queries based on Allen Browne tutorial.

Comment: Hi @June7, Query asks for 2 parameters now viz., Threshold and ItemID. What could be wrong?

Comment: See latest edits. I was mixing query versions in my post. Sorry.

Comment: When i ran the query, it took a long time accessing records. If i moved the record selector to the last row to read the total number of records, its still running since last 10 minutes showing "not responding" in title bar.

Comment: Well, works great with the small dataset provided in example. Yes, complex queries can be prohibitively slow on large datasets. Maybe a VBA solution is in your best interest.

Comment: no issues. Thanks a bunch! But is it a better idea to have 2 separate tables for storing such records (after calculating GAPs and prev/next), like i showed in the screenshots above, which can later be joined using using their GlobalID? Can the query be modified to spit out 2 tables?

Comment: Managed to combine queries 2 and 3. Why save this calculated/manipulated data to any tables? Certainly don't see any advantage to splitting output to 2 tables.

Comment: BTW i finally got the total count. it is showing 603 instead of 269 unique items. In excel sheet i am getting 269.

Comment: If you want to provide spreadsheet of complete dataset, I will test with. I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: here is the Box link @June7 : [link](https://app.box.com/s/apcuktwat8ru70k7pz9okae2g3af0hxf)

Comment: I have added the formulae to show how i calculated the Previous / Current as well as Gap.

Comment: Version Date values appear to be inconsistent structure. Some are 10 characters (with placeholder zeros) and are international date format, others are shorter (no placeholder zeros) and in U.S. date format. I have to get all into U.S. (Access default) format. Will see what I can accomplish tomorrow. Why are rows filtered? What is the criteria?

Comment: Version Date was in text format, so converted it to date and time. See DATA sheet. Rows are filtered to remove the unwanted "-" rows. Count of unique records is 269.

Comment: Had to make an edit in Query2 - Int([Enter Threshold]). I get 268 records but it is so slow - 15 seconds to open and about 3 minutes to read to end. Tried your original query and it is even worse, gave up opening it at all. Larger dataset would be impossible to run - think I would go to a VBA solution. Why does GloblID have 2 lengths (8 and 13 characters)? Should 87170801 and 0000087170801 be same group? I edited to prefix 8 character values with "00000". The output is still 268 records - I had expected fewer after that edit.

Comment: Hi @June7, the GlobalID is text format and prefixed with 0000. I edited and merged 1st two of your queries by just making the Desc into Asc and to make CurDate in Desc order and Prev date in Asc order. Now if we can only pick up the 1st record in a GlobalID group, that would make it correct.
run below query to understand output.

Comment: SELECT [GlobalID], [Version Date] AS CurDate, [ItemID] AS CurItemID, ((SELECT  TOP 1 [Version Date]  FROM Temporary AS Dupe  WHERE Dupe.GlobalID=Temporary.GlobalID AND Dupe.ItemID < Temporary.ItemID ORDER BY Dupe.GlobalID, Dupe.ItemID ASC)) AS PreDate, ((SELECT TOP 1 [ItemID]  FROM Temporary AS Dupe  WHERE Dupe.GlobalID=Temporary.GlobalID AND Dupe.ItemID < Temporary.ItemID  ORDER BY Dupe.GlobalID, Dupe.ItemID ASC)) AS PreItemID FROM Temporary ORDER BY Temporary.[GlobalID], Temporary.[VERSION Date] DESC

Comment: Reversing the sort order makes no sense to me. Earlier date is in the CurDate field and later date in the PreDate field. The 2 queries I suggest do return the most recent record of each GlobalID following your example. I am stumped why Query1 drops records in total count when go to end - made into a table so all 6805 records showed and counted. Query2 still slow and still get 268 records. Think I've contributed all I can to this topic. Considering how slow the queries are, continuing with this approach is impractical. And apparently the number of comments exceeds some recommended limit.

Answer (score 1):

Will offer one more contribution - option with VBA code to get the Current/Previous pairs. This does require saving records to table. Tested and runs in a snap.

```
Sub GetGap()
Dim intTH As Integer, x As Integer, strGID As String
Dim rsT1 As DAO.Recordset, rsT2 As DAO.Recordset
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Temp"
Set rsT1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Temporary ORDER BY GlobalID, ItemID DESC;")
Set rsT2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Temp;")
strGID = rsT1!GlobalID
x = 1
While Not rsT1.EOF
    If strGID = rsT1!GlobalID Then
        If x = 1 Then
            rsT2.AddNew
            rsT2!GlobalID = strGID
            rsT2!CurItemID = rsT1!ItemID
            rsT2!CurDate = rsT1![Version Date]
            x = 2
        ElseIf x = 2 Then
            rsT2!GlobalID = strGID
            rsT2!PreItemID = rsT1!ItemID
            rsT2!PreDate = rsT1![Version Date]
            x = 3
        End If
        If Not rsT1.EOF Then rsT1.MoveNext
    Else
        If x = 3 Then rsT2.Update
        strGID = rsT1!GlobalID
        x = 1
    End If
    If rsT1.EOF Then rsT2.Update
Wend
End Sub
```

Then a query can easily calculate the Gap and filter records.

> SELECT Temp.GlobalID, Temp.CurItemID, Temp.CurDate, Temp.PreDate, Temp.PreItemID, [CurDate]-[PreDate] AS Gap
>   FROM Temp
>   WHERE ((([CurDate]-[PreDate])>Int([Enter Threshold])));

Or the code can be expanded to also calc the Gap and save only records that meet the threshold requirement, just a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hi @June7 i tried to merge the above 2 queries together, but i am getting the following error:

**The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the table or query T1. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.**

Comment: Seems the inner query has to be executed first to generate the table and then only the outer query can be applied on it. Any other way, the 2 queries can be merged into one?

Comment: Not with this particular subquery structure. And No, I do not know any other way to efficiently get Current/Previous by query alone.