# Exporting MS Access query to MS Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a query in Access that uses a UDF, which means that I can't import that query into Excel using the Data>From Access or MS Query.

Is there a way around this> Either by editing the query, using VBA or something else?

Comment: Using a UDF in your query prevents you to pull the data from Excel. Same thing if you use some "non SQL" functions like NZ()

Comment: @iDevlop Yes this is why I am looking for workarounds.

Comment: Have you tried exporting From Access to Excel?

Comment: @marlan It needs to be triggered from Excel end user won't have access to Access

Comment: Have you tried using an `Access.Application` Object?, and exporting from it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling UDF from query, use VBA to update a table with the calculated result. Yes, saving calculated data is usually BAD, but sometimes just gotta do what ya gotta do. I use temp tables (table is permanent, data is temporary) for some complicated data manipulation processes that can't be done easily or efficiently with queries alone. Data saved to and resides in table only for the time needed by the process and is purged before or after running procedure. In a split db, if multiple users all have access to the procedure, temp table needs to be in frontend so each user has their own instance of table and they won't conflict with each other. Here is one example [VBA in lieu of slow queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-showing-min-and-max-pairs-as-a-single-row-having-difference-greater-th/42967703#42967703)