# Trying to do a calculation with data from a date and the data from the day before

Tags: ms-access

I have made a report in which i have grouped by day.

I am trying to calculate the fuel consumption per plant expressed in liters per hour.

To do this you take the

```
[LitersIssued]Today/[Hourmeter]Today-[Hourmeter]Yesterday
```

How would i get the value of Hourmeter for Yesterday(or the last date when the plant ran)

Example of Table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry7Md.png]

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-showing-min-and-max-pairs-as-a-single-row-having-difference-greater-th/42911185#42911185

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for showing min and max pairs as a single row having difference greater than a gap threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-showing-min-and-max-pairs-as-a-single-row-having-difference-greater-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
[LitersIssued]/([Hourmeter]-DLookup("Hourmeter","[YourTableName]","PlantNumber=" & [PlantNumber] & " AND Dates=#" & FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d",-1,[Dates]),2) & "#")))))
```

Not the most efficient way to do it and probably needs some null values and division by zero protection but pretty straightforward and can be included in an Access SQL statement.

Comment: The method will work, but you should use: `Format(DateAdd("d",-1,[Dates]),"yyyy\/mm\/dd")` as _FormatDateTime_ returns localised strings.