# office access substrac values from each row in one field

Tags: ms-access

Please help, how to substract values in one field from one row to another, for example:
[image: from this field]

I want it become like this:
[image: the values from total substract from each row]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen)

Answer (score 1):

This Question is not very clear but I've given what you have asked for.
This will place the first total in the row with NO = 1 and then will reduce that total as NO increases.

```
(Select Total from table1 where Date1 = (Select Min(NO) from Table1))-IIf([No]=1,0,(DSum("[Total]","[Table1]","[NO]<=" & [NO] & " AND [NO]<>1")))
```

Add this as the last column in a query on your table. You will have to replace "Table1" with your table name and you should really change the column names to be something different than NO and Date as these are used for other things in Access.

Comment: Thanks for the rep, after i tried the query above i keep having empty result, here is the file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BylbIrxnANGJdlZiQjA5NDRYUE0

Answer (score 0):

The way you have data stored could make this impossible because there is no way to distinguish which records should be subtracted from which records. That is assuming there will be more than one record considered a positive (increase) entry. Options:

1. Another field that identifies record as either Increase or Decrease
2. Enter the values to be subtracted as negatives

Regardless of which you choose, a report is the easiest way to show a running balance because textbox on report has RunningSum property.

But if these records are not incoming and outgoing transactions and what you really want is for each record to get value from previous and subtract, then review [Stackoverlow - get previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen)

Why do you name fields with Kmh/mph, those values are obviously not Kmh/mph, they look like odometer readings. Better field names may be OldOdometer, NewOdometer. However odometer readings would increase, not decrease. Why do you need to add new to old? Just what is this data?

Comment: Sory for not being clear before, anwy here the file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BylbIrxnANGJdlZiQjA5NDRYUE0

Comment: See revised answer.