# Row Difference along a column in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have at table with 114 different `site ID` and `numericresult` and date collected. There are multiple `numericresult` for each `Site ID` as we collect data monthly. Now I am trying to get the difference of numeric result according to respective site ID. The table is:

```
Site ID      CollectDate           NumericResult
1H-1          2/15/2014                 3.2
1H-1          6/22/205                  3.5
2H-4          3/16/2015                 3.0
2H-4          4/20/2014                 2.8
2H-4          2/15/2014                 3.3
1H-11         3/16/2015                 2.9
1H-11         5/12/2016                 3.4
```

I have around 22000 of the data with 114 'Site ID' here.

I would like to get something as:

```
Site ID                 NumericResult      Diff
1H-1                           3.2          0
1H-1                           3.5          0.3
2H-4                           3.0          0
2H-4                           2.8          0.2
2H-4                           3.3          0.5
1H-11                          2.9          0
1H-11                          3.4          0.5
```

For the negative value I want to use absolute of that one too.
I would appreciate any help on this. 
Update: Following the site and looking over the same site given I got this:

```
SELECT GIS_allCL2.[Site ID], GIS_allCL2.NumericResult, GIS_allCL2.NumericResult-(SELECT TOP 1 NumericResult FROM GIS_allCL2 AS Q 
WHERE GIS_allCL2.[Site ID]=Q.[Site ID]
AND Q.NumericResult < GIS_allCL2.NumericResult
ORDER BY Q.[Site ID] DESC) AS Diff

FROM GIS_allCL2
WHERE
 (SELECT TOP 1 NumericResult FROM GIS_allCL2 AS Q
WHERE GIS_allCL2.[Site ID]=Q.[Site ID] AND Q.NumericResult< GIS_allCL2.NumericResult) Is Not Null

ORDER BY GIS_allCL2.[Site ID], GIS_allCL2.NumericResult;
```

Doesn't work :(

I have my table as GIS_allCL2. 
more help please.

UPdate:

I have updated the table as there are numericresult for same date in muliple siteID. It is still not working. 
Please help!

Update:

The query works fine with sql provided by 'June7', however at the end it throws error: AT MOST ONE RECORD CAN BE RETURNED BY THIS SUBQUERY. 
I know I have 114 site ID with different dates from 2014-2017 and numericresult for the dates. SO one Site ID has multiple collectdate and some site ID may have exact same collectdate. so getting rid of error is a challenge here. 
Please Help!

Comment: Getting value from another record of same table is common question. Search forum and review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen)

Comment: @June7: Do I really have to go through VBA, can't I just do in SQL?

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K for the edit and the link. I went though them and found one but did not work on mine :(

Comment: @Dadep   Thank you for the edit and format. I am new to this site really appreciate your support.

Comment: The links I provided show query only solutions as well as a VBA alternative.

Comment: @June7 I went through the link you have provided and tried to learn something but being a novice I am kind a lost as the difference there was obtained through threshold and with three step query. I wonder if we could do this in one query and moreover, the difference is according to the Site ID here . I am very confused and lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Allen Browne subquery basics](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord) as guide, consider:

```
SELECT SiteID, NumericResult, CollectDate, 
Abs(NumericResult-(SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.NumericResult FROM GIS_allCL2 As Dupe WHERE Dupe.SiteID=GIS_allCL2.SiteID AND Dupe.CollectDate<GIS_allCL2.CollectDate ORDER BY Dupe.CollectDate DESC)) AS Diff
FROM GIS_allCL2 ORDER BY SiteID, CollectDate;
```

Suggestion for when a SiteID has multiple same date records. Requires a unique record identifier, such as an autonumber field, here it is called ID:

```
SELECT SiteID, NumericResult, CollectDate, 
Abs(NumericResult-(SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.NumericResult FROM GIS_allCL2 As Dupe WHERE Dupe.SiteID=GIS_allCL2.SiteID AND Format(Dupe.CollectDate, "yyyymmdd") & Format(Dupe.ID,"0000")<Format(GIS_allCL2.CollectDate,"yyyymmdd") & Format(GIS_allCL2.ID,"0000") ORDER BY Dupe.CollectDate DESC, Dupe.ID DESC)) AS Diff
FROM GIS_allCL2 ORDER BY SiteID, CollectDate, ID;
```

Comment: It is throwing me syntax error in the query expression. The table I have has multiple data(NumericResult) for different Site ID at same collectdate. Will that be the reason for the error?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I edited answer to add CollectDate field to the query and forgot to put comma after the field. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Its seems like it is subtracting all the values from top1.  I mean it is taking top1 value and subtracting other values from that but not along the rows.

Comment: It is actually taking 3.2 the top numericresult and subtracting all other rows with this 3.2. it is giving me:
Site ID                 NumericResult      Diff
1H-1                           3.2          0
1H-1                           3.5          0.3
2H-4                           3.0          0.2
2H-4                           2.8          0.4
2H-4                           3.3          0.1
1H-11                          2.9          0.3
1H-11                          3.4          0.2

Comment: June7  I tried with modifying but still the same result.. do I have to add another query?

Comment: Okay, did another edit on answer. Think I really got it this time. That's what happens when trying to rush during work breaks. However, because the query orders by CollectDate, the output order is slightly different from your example.

Comment: That's great! I first tried with asce then saw yours as desc and I was like WHOooaa missed that.

Comment: Well it also gives me error after I scrolled down to end as: 
"At most one record can be returned by this query". It looks fine but are there any reasons to show that?

Comment: Well, used the tips from "allenbrowne" for the error and added the '[Site ID]' after DSCE didn't help. 
How do I get unique ID for each rows now..

Comment: So the example data is not representative. Allen Browne instruction is to include a unique record identifier (primary key), such as an autonumber field. The SiteID is not unique and therefore not a primary key. However, even including PK will not help to calculate a difference of two values that have the same date. I've never had to deal with that and unfortunately I don't see any way to accomplish that with this method.

Comment: And almost as soon as I say 'cannot do', I envision a solution. See revised answer.

Comment: Can we just work with siteID and NumericResult and then join the result to the collectDate rather than ORDER BY clause with CollectDate?? I am curious if that would workout. Ill check it tho.