# How to do conditional formatting on access based on two consecutive rows

Tags: ms-access

I have the following table in microsoft access 2012:

```
ID  PatientID   Prescription date   Drug    Prescription end date
1   1           12/01/2015          A       18/01/2015
2   1           23/02/2015          A       01/03/2015
3   1           01/03/2015          A       15/03/2015
4   1           15/03/2015          A       30/03/2015
5   1           05/06/2015          A       10/06/2015
```

I want to get an output that looks like this:

```
ID  PatientID   Epistart DATE   Drug    Epi end date
1   1           12/01/2015          A       18/01/2015
2   1           23/02/2015          A       30/03/2015
3   1           05/06/2015          A       10/06/2015
```

So, in other words:

1. When the start date of the next row is the same as end date row of the previous, take the late date in that series
2. Group that episode as one and give only one row for that episode then

Comment: Conditional formatting has nothing to do with your question. Although i don't see a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen)

Comment: It's simple enough to return value of previous record but not understanding the logic for the output. What defines a 'series'? Edit your question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

there is no unique value that ties record 2 start date to record 4 end date.