# ACCESS 2016 SQL - getting only rows of value change

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm tracking data collected on a daily basis. I've organized the data and keep each days sample separate by a data/time stamp column. What I'm trying to do is do an inner join to compare the data on subsequent rows. Only displaying rows where the status has changed from the last row.

I'm displaying two date samples in each row the reference and the comparative.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
    SELECT StatusHistory.RecID
          ,StatusHistory.SampleDT
          ,StatusHistory.Status
          ,Change.SampleDT
          ,Change.Status
     FROM StatusHistory
     INNER JOIN StatusHistory AS Change ON (StatusHistory.RecID = 
           Change.RecID  AND StatusHistory.Status <> Change.Status)
     WHERE StatusHistory.RecID=[@IDvalue];
```

Here is the table structure, and no, RecID is not the identity key in this table.

[image]

The RecID is an identity field from the table that the sample is being taken from. My objective is to show the status change for RecID's over time and I'm most interested in the point of change from one Status value to another.

If I run the query as is I get nothing. Same query removing the "AND StatusHistory.Status <> Change.Status" and it will yield comparatives of ever occurrence of RecID in the table compared to every other row where that RecID value is present.

Comment: Please show your table  schema and what results you are currently getting vs. what results you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query for getting value from another record in same table and filter by difference greater than a gap threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903785/query-for-getting-value-from-another-record-in-same-table-and-filter-by-differen)

Comment: RecID is unique record identifier? How could joining to itself be useful? If RecID is guaranteed to be sequential (no gaps), join RecID to RecID+1.

Comment: Sample data, current result and expected result (as [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) may help.

Comment: If I were on SQL Server I believe this would work, but I don't know the equivelent, if any, in MS-Access SQL: 
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT value, time, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY Time)
  FROM dbo.table
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1;